# sudo up to root -- I'm not sure if I understand the phrasing correctly

Tags: comprehension

Source: [The Official Ubuntu Server Book, 3nd Edition by Kyle Rankin and Benjamin Mako Hill (2014)](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/program/Rankin-Official-Ubuntu-Server-Book-The-3rd-Edition/PGM229218.html)

Example:

> This way you force users to log in with their regular accounts and **sudo up to root**, and you also prevent a user from being able to guess the root password and gain access.

Is *sudo up to* used as a phrasal verb there? *sudo* is the name of the command on Linux systems that gives you elevated rights over the system (actually, what it really does is it makes you the root user for a very brief period of time). And *root* is the default system administrator account on all Linux systems.

Comment: I think this sounds fine. It reads to me like   *... and step up to `root` ...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sudo:

> is a program for Unix-like computer operating systems that allows users to run programs with the security privileges of another user, by default the superuser. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo))

The root account is 'above' normal users, so to *'sudo up to'* is another way of saying to *elevate* privileges.

In this case, 'to sudo up' is used as a phrasal verb, although it's quite rare.  Normally phrasal verbs are things like to 'look down on' or to 'see to', which are more common.